# Organization chart: How can I add a combined entry at the bottom using forest?

Tags: forest

I am trying to add a combined entry in an organization chart that looks like in the image show.
Thank you in advance.[image]

```
\documentclass[border=20pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}

\forestset{
  direction switch/.style={
    for tree={edge+=thick, font=\sffamily},
    where level>=2{folder, grow'=0}{for children=forked edge},
    where level=4{}{draw},
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  % forest preamble: determine layout and format of tree
  direction switch,
  [a - general chamber
   [b - chamber
    [c - chamber
      [d - chamber
                [ (e - chamber)]
        ]
    ]
    [f - chamber
      [g - chamber
                [h - chamber]
                [i - chamber]
      ]
      [j - chamber
      ]
    ]
   ]
  [k - chamber
    [l - chamber
      [m - chamber
      [n - chamber
      ]
      ]
      [o - chamber
      ]
   ]
 ]    
 ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to the site. This is a great first question ;). You can't per se do this with `forest`, but you can fake it using `forest` apparatus.

Answer (score 2):

*Note that if you found the code you posted somewhere, note that you should attribute it (ideally with a link, but at least with an author).*

`forest` can't do this as such because nodes can only have a single parent. However, you can fake it using the package's apparatus. Since you'd also otherwise need another change of growth direction for a single `node`, it's easiest to just fake the whole thing.

```
\documentclass[border=20pt,tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage[edges]{forest}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\forestset{
  direction switch/.style={
    for tree={edge+=thick, font=\sffamily},
    where level>=2{folder, grow'=0}{for children=forked edge},
    where level=4{}{draw},
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  % forest preamble: determine layout and format of tree
  direction switch,
  [a - general chamber
   [b - chamber
    [c - chamber
      [d - chamber
                [ (e - chamber)]
        ]
    ]
    [f - chamber
      [g - chamber
                [h - chamber]
                [i - chamber]
      ]
      [j - chamber, tikz+={\node [draw, anchor=north] (extra) at ([yshift=-20pt]!c.south -| {$(!c)!.5!(ochamber)$}) {ABC};
        \draw [thick] (!c) -- ++(0pt,-15pt) coordinate (a) -| (extra.north) (ochamber.south) -- (ochamber.south |- a) -| (extra.north);
      }
      ]
    ]
   ]
  [k - chamber
    [l - chamber
      [m - chamber
      [n - chamber
      ]
      ]
      [o - chamber, name=ochamber
      ]
   ]
 ]    
 ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: tree with 'fake' two-parent node]